# Creating cookie for each tab seperatly

Tags: php, javascript

I have made a grid like google to show images and it get loaded on scroll down. 
On history back click I want to show the loaded images again. 
That is why, On each scroll down I have stored the last loaded page no. in cookie. But an issue come out when I load the same grid page in two tabs in same browser.
Is there any way to create cookies for each tab separately.

I have used following code to create and erase cookies.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        //var text = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: The use of `sessionStorage` would be more helpful ... or even using `window.name`.

Comment: Why would session.storage help? Or window.name?

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies are 'domain' wide, they aren't tab or window specific.

Also, it sounds like what your looking for is 'pushState' - which is part of HTML5.
Some useful resources:

-http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Also a polyfil available here:

-https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

hope this helps!